# Having issue with connection between docker container and postgres cannot run localhost:3001

Tags: javascript, reactjs, postgresql, docker-compose

I just started working with docker containers, I was able to connect my postgres databese and server successfully with Dockers, howevevr, when I'm runinng localhost:3001/profile in the fronted I'm getting this error message in the terminal

[image: dokcer error message]

Is there anything I'm missing

this is my fronend code where i'm trying to run it
profile.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './Profile.css';

class Profile extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: this.props.user.name,
      age: this.props.user.age,
      pet: this.props.user.pet,
    };
  }

  onFormChange = event => {
    switch (event.target.name) {
      case 'user-name':
        this.setState({ name: event.target.value });
        break;
      case 'user-age':
        this.setState({ age: event.target.value });
        break;
      case 'user-dog':
        this.setState({ pet: event.target.value });
        break;
      default:
        return;
    }
  };

  onProfileUpdate = data => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:3001/profile/${this.props.user.id}`, {
      method: 'post',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({ formInput: data }),
    })
      .then(resp => {
        this.props.toggleModal();
        this.props.updateState({ ...this.props.user, ...data });
      })
      .catch(console.log);
  };
  render() {
    const { user } = this.props;
    const { name, age, pet } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className='profile-modal'>
        <article className='br3 ba b--black-10 mv4 w-100 w-50-m w-25-l mw6 shadow-5 center bg-white'>
          <main className='pa4 black-80 w-80'>
            <img src='http://tachyons.io/img/logo.jpg' className='br4- h4 w3 dib' alt='avatar' />
            <h1>{this.state.name}</h1>
            <h4>{`Images Submitted: ${user.entries}`}</h4>
            <p>{`Member since: ${new Date(user.joined).toLocaleDateString()}`}</p>
            <hr />

            <label className='mt2 fw6' htmlFor='user-name'>
              Name:
            </label>
            <input
              onChange={this.onFormChange}
              className='pa2  ba  w-100'
              placeholder={user.name}
              type='text'
              name='user-name'
              id='name'
            />
            <label className='mt2 fw6' htmlFor='user-age'>
              Age:
            </label>
            <input
              onChange={this.onFormChange}
              className='pa2  ba  w-100'
              placeholder={user.age}
              type='text'
              name='user-age'
              id='age'
            />
            <label className='mt2 fw6' htmlFor='name'>
              Pet:
            </label>
            <input
              onChange={this.onFormChange}
              className='pa2  ba  w-100'
              placeholder={user.pet}
              type='text'
              name='user-pet'
              id='pet'
            />
            <div className='mt4' style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
              <button
                onClick={() => this.onProfileUpdate({ name, age, pet })}
                className='b pa2 grow pointer hover-white w-40 bg-light-blue b--black-20'>
                Save
              </button>
              <button
                className='b pa2 grow pointer hover-white w-40 bg-light-red b--black-20'
                onClick={this.props.toggleModal}>
                Cancel
              </button>
            </div>
          </main>
          <div className='modal-close' onClick={this.props.toggleModal}>
            &times;
          </div>
        </article>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Profile;
```

this is my Dokcer-compsoer.yml

version: "3.9"

services:
#backend API
smart-brain-api:
container_name: backend
build: ./
command: nodemon server.js
working_dir: /usr/src/smart-brain-api
environment:
POSTGRES_URI: postgres://moshe:Moshe6700@postgres:5432/smart-brain-docker
links:
- postgres
ports:
- "3001:3001"
volumes:
- ./:/usr/src/smart-brain-api

```
# postgres
```

postgres:
environment:
POSTGRES_USER: moshe
POSTGRES_PASSWORD: Moshe6700
POSTGRES_DB: smart-brain-docker
POSTGRES:_HOST: postgres
build: ./postgres
ports:
- "5432:5432"

Comment: So you're trying to query a table `user` that doesn't exist?

Comment: I added a Modal to my frontend, and I'm trying to update the users name and this is what I'm getting in the terminal,

and in the console in the network tab i'm getting "error updating user", the error message i gave to my server.js, if something goes wrong